# How to show all nested DIVs inside a main DIV with title tag?

Tags: jquery, html

I have my main `div` with `title="apple"` and nested divs with no title tag. When I write code to show main div with `"apple"` title only the main `div` is getting displayed, the nested divs doesn't get displayed. How to display all child divs even if they don't have title tag? Here is the code below.

```
<div title="apple">
  <div>Hi..</div>
</div>
```

And the jQuery

```
$('input#showapple').click(function(){
  $("div *[title='apple']").show(2000);
});

$('input#hideapple').click(function(){
  $("div *[title='apple']").hide(2000);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do them both in one using `toggle` **plus** you don't need to specify the `input` argument when selecting by ID, jQuery **will only return the first matched element on ID** (because there should only be one):

```
$('#showapple, #hideapple').click(function(){
    $("div[title='apple'] > div").toggle(2000);
});
```

Comment: @DarrenDavies ;). 49 to go for you ey?

Comment: yeah - I'd be nearly there but someone stole all the rep for the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="apple">
```

You select elements using attribute ID, not title.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('input#showapple').click(function(){
   $("div[title='apple'] > div").show(2000);
});
```

You will select all the div with title apple and any child div's within it.

http://jsfiddle.net/rpZbL/

Answer (score 0):

your selector seems to be a little bit off

```
$('input#showapple').click(function(){
    $("div[title=apple]").show(2000);
});
```

also, you should really be using classes for this and not the title.